# VS2019 Wont show projects in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I have installed VS2019 community edition, I have also installed the

- .NET 3.0 SDK 32 and 64 bit versions
- .NET 3.0 Runtime 32 and 64 bit versions

But when I attempt to create a new project in VS2019, I get the file/project created ok on disk, but solution explorer is just not recognizing it at all as a project

I have tried uninstalling many times, just happens again and again like this

Does anyone have any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok so by blind luck I uninstalled .NET Core 3.0 runtime/SDK, and attempted to create an older project (WPF using .NET Framework 4.7.2) and saw this error come up

`Cannot open any project in Visual Studio 2019: The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized`

Which allowed me to google, and lead me to this page https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/515088/cannot-open-any-project-in-visual-studio-2019-the.html

Which in turn had this information on in

> This happens because you have older versions of msbuild assemblies in the GAC which gets loaded when trying to use a newer version of VS (2019). We don’t support this mixed mode development.
>
> Run the following commands from an elevated Visual Studio Developer Command prompt:

```
gacutil /u “MSBuild, Version=15.1.0.0”
gacutil /u “Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core, Version=15.1.0.0”
gacutil /u “Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0”
gacutil /u “Microsoft.Build.Engine, Version=15.1.0.0”
gacutil /u “Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0”
gacutil /u “Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0”
gacutil /u “Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0”
```

After I did that, I was able to reinstall .NET Core 3.0 runtime/SDK and all was ok